# Generate Org-mode objects programmatically

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I want to generate strings containing Org-mode text without actually hard-coding the syntax. For example i want to run a function such as `(org-generate (org-generate-heading "heading" (org-generate-plain-list '("foo" "bar" "baz")))` and it will return:

```
* heading
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
```

In other words, i want to create Org-mode documents of arbitrary complexity without micromanaging syntactic features like asterisks and indentation, only via calling functions with parameters, that return some Org objects. Is it possible to do that? Maybe via `org-element`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your example doesn't say anything about context.

Comment: I would recommend looking at `org-capture-templates`, because it seems very similar to what you want to todo.

Comment: `org-element-interpret-data` could probably be your `org-generate`, but the data seems to need a lot of details about positions, levels, bullets etc. so `org-generate-heading` and friends would still need to be written and would be nontrivial.

Answer (score 5):

**INITIAL** (March 14, 2014):  First rough draft.

**EDIT** (March 15, 2014):  Created and revised the function named `example`.  The path of the let-bound variable `org-file` must coincide with an existing org-mode file.  The let-bound variables `main-heading` and `sub-heading` are not being used at this time due to an apparent limitation with using variables in a list that begins with `'(` -- i.e., those two variables are not recognized under this circumstance.  The function `org-capture` from `org-capture.el` has been modified to include *the contents of* the function `org-capture-set-plist`, which in turn has been modified to eliminate the first two elements of `org-capture-entry` (aka `org-capture-templates`) -- both entries (i.e., `:key` and `:description`) are for manually selecting a template from the user-interface, and are not needed when generating an org buffer programmatically as is being done with this `example`.  In addition, the portions of the function `org-capture` relating to manually selecting a template have been removed.

**EDIT** (March 16, 2014):  Revised variables and list handling based upon lessons provided by @sds and @lunaryorn in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22440518/2112489   Added four *optional* incoming variables -- **(1)** `main-heading`; **(2)** `sub-heading-headline`; **(3)** `sub-heading-complete`; and **(4)** `plain-list`.  The example now work either interactively, or by evaluating the function using the following format:  `(org-generate "PROJECT" "Thesis" "** Thesis\n:PROPERTIES:\n:END:" '("a" "b" "c"))`

**EDIT** (March 19, 2014):  `org-generate` is now a non-interactive function that requires incoming variables -- the doc-string has been updated.  Created a function named `example` that utilizes the new format for `org-generate`.

---

```lisp
;; EXAMPLES:
;; (org-generate 'entry "/Users/HOME/Desktop/myproject.org" "PROJECT" "Thesis" "** Thesis\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :END:")
;; (org-generate 'item "/Users/HOME/Desktop/myproject.org" "PROJECT" "Thesis" nil '("a" "b" "c"))
```

---

```lisp
(defun example ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (org-file "/Users/HOME/Desktop/myproject.org")
      (level-one "TASKS")
      (level-two
        "Active [\#A] Generate Org-mode objects programmatically.")
      (full-level-two (concat
        "** Active [\#A] Generate Org-mode objects programmatically.\n"
        "   DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n"
        "   :PROPERTIES:\n"
        "   :ToodledoFolder: TASKS\n"
        "   :END:"))
       (plain-list '("foo" "bar" "baz")) )
    (org-generate 'entry org-file level-one level-two full-level-two)
    (org-generate 'item org-file level-one level-two nil plain-list) ))

(defun org-generate (type org-file level-one
  &optional level-two full-level-two plain-list)
"Formating options for `org-capture-entry` are similar to `org-capture-templates`.
However, the first two elements (i.e., `:key` and `:description`) are NOT used.
Please see the doc-string of the variable `org-capture-templates` for more info.
  (1) `type`:  required -- 'entry | 'item
  (2) `org-file`:  required -- path to the org-mode file.
  (3) `level-one`:  required -- main heading.
  (4) `level-two`:  optional -- sub-heading headline (only).
  (5) `full-level-two`:  optional -- complete sub-heading.
  (6) `plain-list`:  optional -- a list.
EXAMPLES:
  `(org-generate 'entry org-file level-one level-two full-level-two)`
  `(org-generate 'item org-file level-one level-two nil plain-list)` "
  (require 'org-capture)
  (let (org-capture-entry)
    (cond
      ((eq type 'entry)
        (setq org-capture-entry
          `(entry
            (file+headline ,org-file ,level-one)
              ,full-level-two :empty-lines 1 :immediate-finish t))
        (lawlist-org-capture))
      ((eq type 'item)
        (setq org-capture-entry
          `(item
            (file+olp ,org-file ,level-one ,level-two)
              nil :empty-lines 1 :immediate-finish t))
        (mapcar (lambda (x)
          (progn
            (setcar (nthcdr 2 org-capture-entry) x)
            (lawlist-org-capture) ))
          plain-list)))))

(defun lawlist-org-capture ()
    (let* ((orig-buf (current-buffer))
     (annotation (if (and (boundp 'org-capture-link-is-already-stored)
        org-capture-link-is-already-stored)
         (plist-get org-store-link-plist :annotation)
       (ignore-errors (org-store-link nil))))
     (entry org-capture-entry)
     initial)
      (setq initial (or org-capture-initial
      (and (org-region-active-p)
           (buffer-substring (point) (mark)))))
      (when (stringp initial)
  (remove-text-properties 0 (length initial) '(read-only t) initial))
      (when (stringp annotation)
  (remove-text-properties 0 (length annotation)
        '(read-only t) annotation))
  (setq org-capture-plist (copy-sequence (nthcdr 3 entry)))
  (org-capture-put :target (nth 1 entry))
  (let ((txt (nth 2 entry)) (type (or (nth 0 entry) 'entry)))
    (when (or (not txt) (and (stringp txt) (not (string-match "\\S-" txt))))
      (cond
       ((eq type 'item) (setq txt "- %?"))
       ((eq type 'checkitem) (setq txt "- [ ] %?"))
       ((eq type 'table-line) (setq txt "| %? |"))
       ((member type '(nil entry)) (setq txt "* %?\n  %a"))))
    (org-capture-put :template txt :type type))
  (org-capture-get-template)
  (org-capture-put :original-buffer orig-buf
       :original-file (or (buffer-file-name orig-buf)
              (and (featurep 'dired)
             (car (rassq orig-buf
                   dired-buffers))))
       :original-file-nondirectory
       (and (buffer-file-name orig-buf)
            (file-name-nondirectory
             (buffer-file-name orig-buf)))
       :annotation annotation
       :initial initial
       :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration)
       :default-time
       (or org-overriding-default-time
           (org-current-time)))
  (org-capture-set-target-location)
  (condition-case error
      (org-capture-put :template (org-capture-fill-template))
    ((error quit)
     (if (get-buffer "*Capture*") (kill-buffer "*Capture*"))
     (error "Capture abort: %s" error)))
  (setq org-capture-clock-keep (org-capture-get :clock-keep))
    (condition-case error
        (org-capture-place-template
         (equal (car (org-capture-get :target)) 'function))
      ((error quit)
       (if (and (buffer-base-buffer (current-buffer))
          (string-match "\\`CAPTURE-" (buffer-name)))
     (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
       (set-window-configuration (org-capture-get :return-to-wconf))
       (error "Error.")))
    (if (and (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
       (org-capture-get :clock-in))
        (condition-case nil
      (progn
        (if (org-clock-is-active)
      (org-capture-put :interrupted-clock
           (copy-marker org-clock-marker)))
        (org-clock-in)
        (org-set-local 'org-capture-clock-was-started t))
    (error
     "Could not start the clock in this capture buffer")))
    (if (org-capture-get :immediate-finish)
        (org-capture-finalize))))
```

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/programmatic_org_file.png))</sub>

Comment: I don't think this is quite what OP was looking for.  E.G. the inner text would be something like `(org-generate-headline :deadline "<%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>" :properties '("ToodledoFolder" . "TASKS")`

Comment: @Sean Allred -- This is my best first attempt at programmatically populating an org buffer based upon the guidelines of the question, and it builds upon existing functions in the `org-capture` library.  It *may* give the original poster (or other forum participants) some ideas on how to better handle the issue.  There were *zero* hits on Google for the phrase `"setq org-capture-entry"`, so at the very least, this will help anyone in the future who Googles that variable and wants to know how to programmatically generate an entry in org-mode without the user-interface.

Comment: Still the only example out there on a google search. Unfortunately can't find a way to manipulate existing entries.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas -- this thread does not address manipulating existing entries.  You may wish to post a new question at http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, trying to think of what exactly I'm trying to do to formulate the question.