# Emacs -- How to replace nth element of a list with a let-bound variable

Tags: list, sorting, emacs

I have not found any examples of how to **replace** the `nth` element of a list without first adding *every element* (**one-by-one**) with the function `add-to-ordered-list` -- e.g., `(add-to-ordered-list 'the-list 'a 1)`.  That requires subsequently deleting the element -- e.g., `(delq a the-list)`.  The third step in the process is to add the *new* element -- e.g., `(add-to-ordered-list 'the-list "HELLO-WORLD!" 1)`.  As the following function named `variable-list-example` uses 26 elements, I'm looking for a better way than first adding all 26 elements (**one-by-one**) to essentially assign each element a position number.  The function `add-to-ordered-list` uses a number assignment that is one digit different than the standard `nth` element approach where the first element has a value of `0`, whereas `add-to-ordered-list` uses the value of `1` for the first element.  Here is the link to the documentation for `add-to-ordered-list`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html

In addition, using the combination `'(` at the beginning of a list seems to prevent using a let-bound variable inside the list -- e.g., the let-bound variable appears in the list as `my-variable` instead of `HELLO-WORLD!`.  The only work-around I have found is the above-mentioned example using `add-to-ordered-list` -- which is a lengthy three-step process (i.e., adding each element **one-by-one** at the outset).

To resolve both issues, I am looking for some assistance please to replace the `17th` element of `the-list` (which is the letter `r`) **with** `my-variable` (which is `HELLO-WORLD!`).

---

```
(defun variable-list-example ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (my-variable "HELLO-WORLD!")
      (the-list '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)))
    ;; replace the 17th element of `the-list` with `my-variable`
    (message "Presto -- this is your new list:  %s" the-list)
  ))
```

---

**THE LIST**

```
'(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z)
```

---

**nth ELEMENT -- CHEAT SHEET / LEGEND**

```
element 0:   a
element 1:   b
element 2:   c
element 3:   d
element 4:   e
element 5:   f
element 6:   g
element 7:   h
element 8:   i
element 9:   j
element 10:  k
element 11:  l
element 12:  m
element 13:  n
element 14:  o
element 15:  p
element 16:  q
element 17:  r
element 18:  s
element 19:  t
element 20:  u
element 21:  v
element 22:  w
element 23:  x
element 24:  y
element 25:  z
```

Comment: Side comment: `add-to-list` and `add-to-ordered-list` should only be used on lists kept in global variables.  IOW to change things like configuration vars.  In all other cases, you'll want to use `push`, `cl-pushnew`, `cons`, `nconc`, `setf`, ... instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use [`setcar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setcar.html) and [`nthcdr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/nthcdr.html):

```
(setcar (nthcdr 17 the-list) my-variable)
```

The more common-lisp-like approach is to use [Generalized Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html):

```
(setf (nth 17 the-list) my-variable)
```

Answer (score 6):

Emacs has a concept of [Generalized Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html), which essentially lets you change arbitrary storage places with `setf`.  For instance, you can change `car` and `cdr` places of list, including the `car` returned by `nth`.  Hence, the following code

```
(let ((foo 10)
      (l '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)))
  (setf (nth 4 l) foo)
  l)
```

will return the list `(1 2 3 4 10 6 7 8)`.

To put variables directly into a quoted list, you must change the kind of quoting.  The [standard quote `'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html#Quoting) inhibits **any evaluation** inside the quoted expression.

The special [Backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote) however lets you evaluate expressions inside a quoted expression:

```
(let* ((foo 10)
      (l `(1 2 3 4 5 ,foo 7 foo)))
  l)
```

The leading comma marks the subsequent expression for evaluation, whereas expressions without a leading comma will be taken literally.  In the above example, the first occurrence of `foo` in the list will be evaluated, and hence replace with `10`, whereas the second occurrence ends up literally in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to understand why I had soooo much trouble trying to use a variable inside a list.  The lesson you have provided will come in very handy in the future!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a late answer that's specifically about `add-to-ordered-list`, because I think there's confusion about what it does and how it works.

`add-to-ordered-list` lets you specify (record) a specific order for an individual list element.

But the list can also have elements that have no specific order recorded for them.  These elements are always put at the end of the list, after all of the elements that do have specific recorded orders.

If you want to *replace* an element that has a recorded order then you need to remove it from the list and add its replacement (which is what you guessed).

```lisp
(add-to-ordered-list 'the-list 'a 1) ; Records order 1 for element (symbol) a. 
(delq a the-list) ; Removes a from the list.
(add-to-ordered-list 'the-list 'HELLO 1) ; Records order 1 for element (symbol) HELLO.
```

Some things to add, to help clarify a bit:

1. You can't use a string element, such as `"HELLO"`, because recording orders for elements requires them to be distinguishable using `eq` (not `equal` or `string=`).
2. You can remove the recorded order from an element, instead of removing the element from the list.  If you do that, the element remains in the list, but moves after any elements that have recorded orders.  That's not what you wanted here (you wanted to replace it), but know that it's possible.  You do this by calling `add-to-ordered-list` with the element and with *no* `ORDERED` value (or a `nil` value).
3. Orders recorded for elements need not be specified for all elements (see above), and they need not be consecutive.  All that matters is that they can be compared numerically, so their elements can be ordered.  For example, you can add elements `a`, `b`, and `c' to an empty list, recording orders of 13, 42, and 6 for them, respectively.  The result is the list` (c a b)`, because 6 < 12 < 42.
4. You can even record the same order for more than one list element, in which case those elements are consecutive in the list but the order among them is unimportant.  You can think of the recorded orders as buckets or scores.  All elements with the score 3 appear in the list before all elements with the score 7, and elements with score 3 (or 7) are consecutive.

See also [this emacs.SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/62520/105).