# Emacs View Mail: trouble using vm-imap-account-alist

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a little problem with ViewMail. In a separate file I'm defining variables with the account information of my email accounts, something like this:

```
(setq secret-mail-account-list-1 "imap-ssl:imap.aaa.com:993:*:login:xxx@aaa.com:password")
;;; other email accounts are defined as well
```

I do this to keep my password away from being recorded by Mercurial.

Then, I do write this into `vm-imap-account-alist` in another file:

```
(setq vm-imap-account-alist
      '(
        (secret-mail-account-list-1 "aaamail")
        ;;; other email accounts are here
        )
      )
```

But, after starting ViewMail with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>`vm`<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> I get the following error:

```
vm-imap-parse-spec-to-list: Wrong type argument: sequencep, secret-mail-account-list-1
```

How do I set the string to a variable so it is of the correct type for `vm-imap-parse-spec-to-list`?

Comment: Awhile ago, a forum participant named lunaryorn gave me a lesson regarding using variables inside a list -- perhaps your problem is caused by something similar -- i.e., `secret-mail-account-list-1` is not being evaluated:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22440553/2112489  You could also try putting that entire string inside of the list instead of using the variable to see if it works like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you got this from the [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViewMailAndImap).  It looks like you want to pass the *value* of `secret-mail-account-list-1` to `vm-imap-account-alist` rather than the symbol itself.  To do so, you need to
[`backquote`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) the alist and unquote the symbol with a comma to get its value:

```
(setq vm-imap-account-alist
      `((,secret-mail-account-list-1 "aaamail") ; notice ` and ,
        ;;; other email accounts are here
        ))
```

At any rate, it helps to explain your error message: it looks like `vm-imap-parse-spec-to-list` expects a sequence (hence `sequencep`) such as a string which it converts to a list.  *Symbols* are not sequences, but the *content* of yours is.